# Suggestions for security of hardware and software for an image processing application

Tags: c++, security, ssl-certificate

We have a fluid monitoring physical device(hardware with camera, PCB board, LED lights etc). This hardware is connected to computer via USB cable. It captures images and these images are processed in C++ software on PC. As a security feature, we have already implemented node authentication using cryptoauthentication chips like ATECC608A. More information below.

I wanted to know if there were some other methods which I can use to improve the security further. 
I want to make sure that the device will only work with the laptop/PC which we provide.

**Already implemented**: The PCB board has ATECCX608a cryptoauthentication chip. we store our ssl certificate and verify the certificate chain
and also do random nonce challenge for device authentication. More on this please refer to the link below

https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/Motley/ATECC508A+Node+Authentication+Example+Walk-through

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you want mutual authentication.  You want the PC to authenticate the USB device, but you want the USB device to authenticate the PC as well.  So construct the SSL handshake you are already using to perform a mutual (client) authentication and make sure everyone has certs from the same CA (likely you)